# syntax error in YOWSUP

Tags: python, yowsup

i am following this tutorial : http://xebee.xebia.in/index.php/2013/11/25/yowsup-the-whatsapp-api/

in step 3 
when i execute this on my terminal :

```
$ python yowsup-cli -c config.example -r sms
```

i get a syntax error saying

```
  File "yowsup-cli", line 98
    unistr = str if sys.version_info >= (3, 0) else unicode
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can any body help how can i remove this error

i m a newbie to python

Comment: It looks like you're on a system with 2.4 installed. The ternary operator was added in 2.5

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: yeah i am using python 2.4.1 , will upgrade it and try , thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

yeah that was an old version error. anyway if you get any problem with the regitration process then you can try this guide [yowsup registration guide](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0).